# Issue when sorting after year, month and day

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I've been looking around for similar threads, but none of them seems to work in my case.

I've a tableview which I'm sorting by date and time. And the time seems to work fine. (Since I could use it in march) but once the date went over to April, it does not work anymore and I've no idea how I can fix that.

I'm using Firestore database, and I've added index for "Date" and "Time" as descading.

```
//Choosing collection
            db.collection("rastad").document(authentication!).collection("promenad")
                .order(by: "Date", descending: true)
                .order(by: "Time", descending: true)
                .getDocuments()
```

The result is not what I'm looking for because, when I'm adding a new record it will be placed in the middle of the tableview. (Next to the 8/3/2019, one). But I want it to sort after the month, year and day. So every new record that's added should be placed in the top of the tableview.

I hope you understand what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image: Nana]

Comment: What exactly are your date and time fields?  If they are formatted strings, you are very likely to have problems with sorting, because strings don't always sort chronologically.

Comment: Title say "day, month and year", body says "month, year and day" but what you probably actually want is sort by "year, month, day"!?

Comment: @DougStevenson In firebase it looks like this -> ``Date: "08/04/2019"`` and ``Time: "15:19"``

Comment: @luk2302 That's correct, how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dates are formatted strings like DD/MM/YYYY, which don't sort chronologically very well.  While March 1, 2019 ("01/03/2019") might sort earlier than April 10 ("10/04/2019"), that is only accidental because the first character 0 happens to be less then the first character 1.  Think about how March 11 sorts after April 10, using the same string sorting logic.

Normally you store moments in time using Timestamp type objects in Firestore, or integers when represented in unix time.  Strings are usually avoided.  While sometimes it's more convenient to store strings (if that's what you want to display), the strings are almost always terrible for sorting.

If you absolutely must use a string, your date and time components should be stored biggest unit to smallest unit.  So, for dates, you would have to use YYYYMMDD.  In any event, you should be formatting the dates on the client, using the locale provided by the device (because us Americans prefer MM/DD/YYYY format - weird, huh?).  I know Android provides date and time formatting APIs that respect the user's preferences.  I can only imaging iOS does the same.

Comment: It looks like you asked a whole new question there.  Please limit yourself to one question per post.